# Realm doesn’t work with xUnite and .net core

Tags: .net-core, realm, xunit

I’m having issues running realm with xUnite and Net core. Here is a very simple test that I want to run

```
public class UnitTest1
    {
        [Scenario]
        public void Test1()
        {
            var realm = Realm.GetInstance(new InMemoryConfiguration("Test123"));
            realm.Write(() =>
                        {
                            realm.Add(new Product());
                        });
            var test = realm.All<Product>().First();
            realm.Write(() => realm.RemoveAll());
        }
    }
```

I get different exceptions on different machines (Windows & Mac) on line where I try to create a Realm instace with InMemoryConfiguration.
On Mac I get the following exception

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type realm::IncorrectThreadException: Realm accessed from incorrect thread.
```

On Windows I get the following exception when running

```
ERROR Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. at 
System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Span1 destination) at 
System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.ReadByte() at 
System.IO.BinaryReader.ReadByte() at 
System.IO.BinaryReader.Read7BitEncodedInt() at 
System.IO.BinaryReader.ReadString() at 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.LengthPrefixCommunicationChannel.NotifyDataAvailable() at 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.TcpClientExtensions.MessageLoopAsync(TcpClient client, ICommunicationChannel channel, Action1 errorHandler, CancellationToken cancellationToken) Source: System.Net.Sockets HResult: -2146232800 Inner Exception: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host HResult: -2147467259
```

I’m using Realm 3.3.0 and xUnit 2.4.1
I’ve tried downgrading to Realm 2.2.0, and it didn’t work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem was found in [this Github](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/1035) post

The piece of code from that helped me to solve the issue

```
Realm GetInstanceWithoutCapturingContext(RealmConfiguration config)
{
    var context = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(null);

    Realm realm = null;
    try
    {
        realm = Realm.GetInstance(config);
    }
    finally
    {
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(context);
    }

    return realm;
}
```

Though it took a while for me to apply this to my solution. 
First and foremost, instead of just setting the context to `null` I am using Nito.AsyncEx.AsyncContext. Because otherwise automatic changes will not be propagated through threads, as realm needs a non-null `SynchronizationContext` for that feature to work. So, in my case the method looks something like this

```
public class MockRealmFactory : IRealmFactory
    {
        private readonly SynchronizationContext _synchronizationContext;
        private readonly string _defaultDatabaseId;

        public MockRealmFactory()
        {
            _synchronizationContext = new AsyncContext().SynchronizationContext;
            _defaultDatabaseId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }

        public Realm GetRealmWithPath(string realmDbPath)
        {
            var context = SynchronizationContext.Current;
            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(_synchronizationContext);

            Realm realm;
            try
            {
                realm = Realm.GetInstance(new InMemoryConfiguration(realmDbPath));
            }
            finally
            {
                SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(context);
            }

            return realm;
        }
    }
```

Further, this fixed a lot of failing unit tests. But I was still receiving that same exception - Realm accessed from incorrect thread. And I had no clue why, cause everything was set correctly. Then I found that the tests that were failing were related to methods where I was using async realm api, in particular `realm.WriteAsync`. After some more digging I found the following lines in the realm documentation.

> It is not a problem if you have set `SynchronisationContext.Current` but
>   it will cause WriteAsync to dispatch again on the thread pool, which
>   may create another worker thread. So, if you are using `Current` in your
>   threads, consider calling just `Write` instead of `WriteAsync`.

In my code there was no direct need of using the async API. I removed and replaced with sync `Write` and all the tests became green again! I guess if I find myself in a situation that I do need to use the async API because of some kind of bulk insertions, I'd either mock that specific API, or replace with my own background thread using `Task.Run` instead of using Realm's version.